# How to fetch modified value of a bean property in spring

Tags: spring

I have a simple class registered as a spring bean, let's call it CustomBean

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBean{

private String key;

...getter and setter for key 

}
```

Then I autowire this bean in another configuration class like this

```
public MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private CustomBean customBean;
    
    public someClass myMethod(......){
    
     new Class1.methodCall1(customBean);
     new Class2.methdoCall2(customBean);
    
    }
}
```

To class1 I pass the bean injected in my class and modify the bean value
In class2, I try to fetch the modified value of the same bean but it is always null.

My question is, is this the correct way to modify a bean value and fetch it?

Comment: Why do you need to modify a class-member (a field) of a bean?

Comment: The specified bean is initialized with a null value upon the loading of the Spring context. Its purpose is to monitor the state of another bean, created by Spring, which may become null during certain events. This monitoring bean is set prior to the nullification of the  other bean, allowing for the retention of essential properties for subsequent utilization.

Comment: How is the `CustomBean.key` field set?

Comment: By injecting (autowiring) the customized bean into a class managed by Spring, utilizing its reference, and subsequently passing this reference as an argument to a constructor of a different class, the value is then set within the constructor of the latter class. Notably, this second class is not managed by spring.